# Add/Delete angular2 ng2-cookies to a path

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, angular-cookies

How to add and delete [ng2-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies) from a specific path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install this library, run:

```
$ npm install ng2-cookies
```

Usage:

```
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';

Cookie.set('cookieName', 'cookieValue', 10, '/path');

let myCookie = Cookie.get('cookieName');

let cookielist = Cookie.getAll('/path');

Cookie.delete('cookieName', '/path');
Cookie.deleteAll('/path');
```

Try these in case the cookies set into your single domain is path dependent.

Comment: how can i get a special cookie. i used a ifram in my page and want to fetch its cookie, is it possible?